# Inversion of control - when to use?

Tags: design-patterns, inversion-of-control

In which cases should I use inversion of control - for constructing all application classes or just these that depends on some other object?

Comment: Have a look at this question : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131446/what-is-inversion-of-control-and-when-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, whenever you want loose coupling between classes.

I think that Mark Seemann in his book *[Dependency Injection in .NET](http://manning.com/seemann/)*  has a simple but very true statement about DI/IoC:

> DI enables loose coupling, and loose coupling makes code more maintainable.

So you should use it when you want to have all the advantages that loose coupling brings, to name a few from the book: late binding, extensibility, parallel development capabilities, testability. For all these advantages you pay the cost of implementing and maintaining an IoC solution in your codebase, which for green field projects is IMHO negligible, especially thanks to IoC containers. For ideas on how to implement it globally for your application you may have a look at the [Composition Root Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx).

Of course, it is also possible to implement IoC only for parts of your project, especially if you are working with a brown field project. If you are using an IoC container though, one disadvantage of this approach is that the use of the IoC container may not be transparent anymore, but you have to explicitly call it and ask for the instances that you need (Service Locator Pattern).